# code style for velocity template files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style, velocity, apache-velocity, velocity-template-language

## Problem

The automatic indents in `.vm` files don't behave as I want them to. Below I add the auto formatted file and also the formatting I want.

**The following code snippet is auto formatted by IntelliJ:**

```
#styleTitle('sample-title')

#@styleDescription()
A short description of the component
#end


#@styleComponent('/components/molecules/sampleComponent/sampleComponent', {
    "headline": 'A headline title',
    "alertText": "Alert text example",
    "link" : {
    "href": "www.stackoverflow.com",
    "text": "Click here!"
}
})#end
```

**What I want:**

```
#styleTitle('sample-title')

#@styleDescription()
    A short description of the component
#end


#@styleComponent('/components/molecules/sampleComponent/sampleComponent', {
    "headline": 'A headline title',
    "alertText": "Alert text example",
    "link" : {
        "href": "www.stackoverflow.com",
        "text": "Click here!"
    }
})#end
```

## Question

I couldn't find any additional configuration under `IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Velocity`  to adjust indention for different code blocks.

How can I configure the code style manually for a specific file type in IntelliJ and how does such a configuration file look like?

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Feel free to create feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Here I created an issue for it on YouTrack. Hopefully it won't get closed without a solution like its former issues:

1. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-224925

2. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55660

Comment: here is the issue I reported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274354